# NPM LINK: The difference between importing external modules through package.json and using npm link in Angular

Tags: angular, npm, package.json, libraries, npm-link

I would like to test a new version of angular/cli and core, but I don't want to publish my modules every time. Instead of it I use npm link locally on my PC.

First of all, I would like to import my modules with npm link and not in package.json in the Client-Script. It should run without error - then I could change something in the modules.

Unfortunately I get 2 errors:

1. backbone, jquery and jointjs - libraries could not be found at node_modules/jointjs...
2. If I add these libraries there, the build-process lasts a lot of time and gives nothing.

How do I use the npm link:

1. I cloned all the repositories of the modules (10 Modules) separately in the WebStorm and run "npm install" there.
2. I run the command "build:lib": "ng build module-name" and become a new folder in 'dist/module-name'
3. Then I go in the terminal to the path: "cd dist/module-name" and run the command "npm link".
4. I go back to my client and run there "npm link module-name ... of all 10 Modules together".
5. There are 10 new folders under node_modules and I can use them as libraries.

Unfortunately I can not run the build-command like before, because It seems like not all the libraries from modules will be imported.

What do I do wrong?